# Error initializing Rangy.js in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, rangy, textangular

I'm working on an angular app that uses textAngular, which depends on rangy-core and rangy-selectionsaverestore.  I'm having the following errors with the latest IE:

```
Module 'WrappedSelection' failed to load: Unspecified error.
Error: Unspecified error.
    at Anonymous function (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:2970:29)
    at Anonymous function (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:2923:14)
    at Anonymous function (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:415:21)
    at Module.prototype.init (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:387:13)
    at init (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:294:17)
    at loadHandler (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:3825:17)

Module 'SaveRestore' failed to load: Unable to get property 'isDirectionBackward' of undefined or null reference
TypeError: Unable to get property 'isDirectionBackward' of undefined or null reference
    at Anonymous function (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js:30:9)
    at Anonymous function (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:415:21)
    at Module.prototype.init (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:387:13)
    at init (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:294:17)
    at loadHandler (js/plugins/textAngular/rangy-core.js:3825:17)
```

This error seems to happen during rangy initialization.

What is odd about this is that the TextAngular demo works fine on Internet Explorer. One different between the demo and my application is that I'm using the unminified rangy library.  Finally, these errors do not happen on Chrome or Firefox.

Although the app loads (I think the errors above are just warnings in the console), when I click into the textAngular field, I see the following error:

Object doesn't support property or method 'getSelection'
File: textAngular.js, Line: 693, Column: 4

I can't find anything in the textAngular or rangy github that addresses these problems.  Has anybody encountered these issues before?

If it helps, I can post the link to our application.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen this issue before, but looking at the Rangy code I can see a bug: the selection save/restore module is missing a dependency. I've fixed the issue and will make a bugfix release in the next week or so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think the missing dependency is causing the script to fail in IE, but not other browsers?

Comment: @TimDown, I noticed the commit and updated my files, accordingly.

Now, I only get this error in IE:
`Module 'WrappedSelection' failed to load: Unspecified error.`

Comment: I am too facing the same issue.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by checking the load order of the scripts...look at the example and make sure your scripts are being loaded in the exact order.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like textAngular is initializing rangy select too early. I fixed this issue by updating textAngular/dist/textAngular.js ln 2036 to wait for onload before checking for rangy library

```
    window.onload = function() {
        // Ensure that rangy and rangy.saveSelection exists on the window (global scope).
        // TODO: Refactor so that the global scope is no longer used.
        if(!window.rangy){
            throw("rangy-core.js and rangy-selectionsaverestore.js are required for textAngular to work correctly, rangy-core is not yet loaded.");
        }else{
            window.rangy.init();
            if(!window.rangy.saveSelection){
                throw("rangy-selectionsaverestore.js is required for textAngular to work correctly.");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I got the same error (only when my page was iframed in though) and used this fix. Console still prints the error, but the page loads and works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue.  I tried the window.onload fix suggested but it just got me to another error about textAngularSetup not being loaded.  I took the window.onload fix out and included the textAngularSetup.js file.  It now is working fine in Chrome and IE.  I am confused because I didn't see that file included in the demo.

Comment: Just to clarify in case others are confused as HorseFly: textAngularSetup isn't includen in the demo, as the demo uses textAngular.min.js, which contains textAngular.js and textAngularSetup.js. When you include the window.onload-fix, you'll need to use textAngular.js and then also textAngularSetup.js.

Answer (score 0):

sharing my solution, I also got the same issue in `IE 11(edge mode)`, tried with above solution(window.onload), but issue was still persisted in the app.

I have done following changes,

1. Added `window.onload` as in above solution, **textangular.js - run()** function
2. Replaced **textangular-rangy.min.js** with **rangy.core** and **rangy-selectionsaverestore** dependencies,

Modified the core code to handle the exception,

File: **rangy-core.js,** `line number:2967-2972`

```
                        var r2;
                        try {
                            // code generating above exception 
                            r2 = r1.cloneRange()
                            r1.setStart(textNode, 0);
                            r2.setEnd(textNode, 3);
                            r2.setStart(textNode, 2);
                            sel.addRange(r1);
                            sel.addRange(r2);
                            selectionSupportsMultipleRanges = (sel.rangeCount == 2);
                        } catch (e) {
                            selectionSupportsMultipleRanges = false;
                        }
```

It might help, tested in IE11 and chrome

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue while loading the third party tool into modal popup where i have dependency of  textangular-rangy.min.js

I have replaced textangular-rangy.min.js with rangy.core and rangy-selectionsaverestore dependencies,
Modified the core code to handle the exception,

File: rangy-core.js, line number:2967-2972

```
 var r2;
                        try {
                            // code generating above exception 
                            r2 = r1.cloneRange()
                            r1.setStart(textNode, 0);
                            r2.setEnd(textNode, 3);
                            r2.setStart(textNode, 2);
                            sel.addRange(r1);
                            sel.addRange(r2);
                            selectionSupportsMultipleRanges = (sel.rangeCount == 2);
                        } catch (e) {
                            selectionSupportsMultipleRanges = false;
                        }
```

it works in IE11 and chrome :)